# How can I rotate the camera?

Tags: torchlight-2

I was watching this video for a complete TL2 reskin mod

and I see at 1m48s he rotates the camera.  How can I do this?

Comment: Hi, @bpcookson, welcome to Arqade!  I've slightly modified your question to specifically refer to camera rotation.  If it's possible, you'll get an answer on how to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do that in the game by default. You will need a [camera mod](http://forums.runicgames.com/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=40402) for it.